# dimension of fiber

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\phi:\ X\rightarrow Y$ be a dominant morphism of irreducible algebraic varieties. Then
 there exists a non-empty open set $U\subset Y$ such that

a) $U\subset \phi(X)$

b) $\forall y\in U$, $\dim \phi^{-1}(y)=\dim X-\dim Y$.

My question is in the above theorem, is the condition that X and Y are irreducible necessary?

Comment: Clearly no: pick any map from irreducible X to ireeducible Y which satisfies the hypothesis,  and consider the obvious map from the disjoint union of two copies of X to the disjoint union of two copies of Y.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Oh, I guess I mean can we remove this condition to get a stronger theorem, sorry about the misleading words

Comment: Neither $X$ nor $Y$ have to be irreducible. I don't know where this statement is written down, except for in [these notes](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~speyer/631/Update.pdf) from D. Speyer's course.